# select submatrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix called m as follows

```
> m<-matrix(1:15,3,5)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15
```

I want to remove the first column of this matrix. Within a function I pass a value called *j*, which is always *1* less than the number of columns in *m* (In this example *j* is 4).
Therefore I used the following code

```
 >m[,2:4+1]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7   10   13
[2,]    8   11   14
[3,]    9   12   15
```

But it is giving only the last 3 columns. Then I changed the code as follows

```
 >m[,2:(4+1)]
```

This time I had the correct output.
Also it is giving the same output for following code as well

```
> m[,1:4+1]
```

**Somebody please explain me how the following codes work?**

```
>m[,2:4+1]
>m[,1:4+1]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`:` has higher precedence than `+`, therefore `2:4+1` gets interpreted at `(2:4)+1` which is the same as `3:5`:

```
2:4+1
[1] 3 4 5
```

Similarly, `1:4+1` gets interpreted as `2:5`:

```
1:4+1
[1] 2 3 4 5
```

To remove columns in a matrix, its probably easier to use the negative subscript input to `[`:

```
m[,-1]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    7   10   13
[2,]    5    8   11   14
[3,]    6    9   12   15
```